# Hive CASE not working in filter condition

Tags: hive, apache-zeppelin

I'm facing an issue with a filter condition in Hive with CASE WHEN clause. Below are the statement and error:

Statement:

```
select day 
from db.tableName 
where case when length(day) <> '19' then substr(day,1,19) else day end
```

Error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: filter expression 'CASE WHEN (NOT length(tableName.`day`) = '19') THEN substring(tableName.`day`, 1, 19) ELSE tableName.`day` END' of type string is not a boolean.;;

If I put case clause in `select` clause, the statement runs perfectly but put in where condition creates the error mentioned. Although the error I captured is from `Zeppelin` but the same error of string type isn't boolean is on `Beeline` as well.

Any pointers on the issue?

Comment: what are you trying to get as a result? the error is because `where` should include a condition, i.e a value compared with another, which returns a `boolean` to help `select` rows. In your case, the comparator and a condition is missing.

Comment: The `day` column contains timestamp type values some in the format `2018-01-01 10:00:00.0` and some in the format `2018-01-01 10:00:00`. I'm trying to convert the `.0` values to the ones excluding it.

Comment: should the table be overwritten with these values or do you just want to `select`?

Comment: Just the `select`. The transformed values I'll write in another table.

Comment: you should then use the `case` expression in `select`. A `where` isn't needed.

Comment: If that were possible I'd not have come here :)
It's out of the question. I'm trying to accomplish that in Spark SQL as well. If that works, I'll include the DF inside the query. But yeah, inside `select` is not a case for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You don't have to use WHERE clause here.

Try following :

```
select case 
      when length(day) <> '19' then substr(day,1,19) 
      else day 
      end
      from db.tableName;
```

Comment: the OP mentions he can get the result with a `select`. this is not the expected answer.

Comment: He has clearly mentioned the query doesn't work with `WHERE` and  `CASE` together - "If I put case clause in select clause, the statement runs perfectly but put in where condition creates the error mentioned."